# Will a unique index for created_at column in Rails 5 prevent records created at the same time?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I ran into an issue where my app receives multiple api calls that call a function that creates a record and then the function validates if a newer record exists already to make sure to run only the function for the newest record.

Sometimes, API calls come in too fast in such way that the "created_at" field displays the same Date & Time. I understand that these are different values even though they display the same time because the Time class also compares fractions of seconds ( which are different ).

Does adding a unique index for the created_at column along with any other column ( that I will choose ) avoid the creation of two records that came in maybe because of an api "*hiccup*" 
Or will the unique index validation consider the seconds fractions for the created_at column?

Im using POSTGRESQL.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having two rows where the `ts` column is in the same second, you can use

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON tab (date_trunc('second', ts));
```

Comment: This does make sense, but how to do this using ActiveRecord instead of directly on POSTGRESQL?

Comment: No idea. Does ActiveRecord keep you from using SQL?